# 3 cables in one box wiring issue

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

My house was built in the 50's.  In my master bedroom I need to replace the fan, so I disassembled it, bought the new fan and am looking at the wiring with a serious question here.  There are three cables coming in, black and white only.  All three blacks are wired together.  Two of the whites are wired together with a pigtail hanging down and the other white as my two connectors.  Is this even remotely normal or am I missing something here?  The fan / light combo was fully functional, but it just doesn't look right.  I hooked a normal/plain light to it and it works, but am still concerned.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds okay to me. I'm guessing one cable is the feed to the box, another goes to the switch, and the final cable goes off to some other part of the circuit.  The black wire in the cable going to the switch, is connected to the black feed wire. The white wire in the cable going to the switch, brings switched power back to the fixture. Since the cable only has two wires, the white was repurpsed to be the switched "hot" lead. This is fine, though the wire should be marked in some way at both ends to indicate that it's no longer a "neutral".

This is what the circuit looks like.

[image]

Comment: I will give this a shot tomorrow afternoon.  I appreciate your time, Will let you know how it goes.